# How to translate squire and page

Tags: translation

My teacher wants me to write about Game of thrones in Chinese. I am facing the problem of accurately translating medieval titles into Chinese. For “squire” I found the translation:

> 鄉紳: Country gentleman; squire

Since that is a Chinese title, I am unsure, if squire is meant in the sense I intend - that is someone who was a page and is waiting on a Knight.

Analogously, I found

> 小廝: young male servant, page
>
> 書童: page boy
>
> 小么兒: page boy

But I am unsure whether any of these can be applied in the context of knighthood, as opposed to hotels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of thing you can check out [91dict.com](http://www.91dict.com).

The subtitle group 人人影视字幕组 have complied a dictionary from their subtitle translations.

For instance if you look up [squire](http://www.91dict.com/words?w=squire) under 基本释义 we get:

> n. 乡绅；侍从；大地主；地方法官
>
> vt. 随侍；护卫
>
> n. (Squire)人名；(英)斯夸尔

and under 场景例句 there are example sentences from Game of Thrones including:

> 来自《冰与火之歌：权力的游戏 第4季 第3集》
>
> There has never lived a more loyal squire.
>
> 世上从无你这般忠心的侍从

and

> He was a squire until a few months ago.
>
> 他之前一直是侍从 数月前才受封

Seems like they really like **侍从** for squire.

---

For [page](http://www.91dict.com/words?w=page) they give:

> 男侍者

Answer (score 1):

"鄉紳" are gentlemen in village, no military aspect

if you want some terms that "squire was typically a teenaged boy, training to become a knight", i would suggest:

"義勇", or "鄉勇"

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000151550

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000109962

Answer (score 1):

Starting from English and trying to take over the sense:

squire 持盾者

early 13c., "young man who attends a knight," later "member of the landowning class ranking below a knight" (c. 1300), from Old French esquier "squire," literally "**shield carrier**"

农 场主
Meaning "country gentleman, **landed proprietor**" is from 1670s; as a general term of address to a gentleman, it is attested from 1828.

page 侍从， 侍从官

"youth, lad, boy of the lower orders," c. 1300, originally also "youth preparing to be a knight," from Old French page "a youth, page, **servant**" (13c.)